# Make one div slide over another using only CSS

Tags: html, css, animation

I am attempting to have 2 divs of the same size, one is initially visible while the other (below?) is initially hidden.

I desire that when you hover over the first div, the other will animate and slide upward to fully cover the first. This one should remain in place until you stop hovering over the area.

I can get a second div to move upward on hover, but it has many unwanted effects - such as a jumpy/jittery behaviour when the second div is in place - and in this fiddle, the lower one begins visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/cc28samh/1/

**the HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="stay-in-place">
        <h1>hello world</h1>
        <p>ipsum dolorum caveat emptor veni vidi vici</p>
    </div>
    <div id="move-in-to-place">
        <h2>I'm on top</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**the style**

```
<style type="text/css"> #stay-in-place {
    position:relative;
    height : 200px;
    width : 200px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: height 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: height 1s, transform 1s;
}
#stay-in-place:hover {
    height : 0px;
}
#move-in-to-place {
    position:absolute;
    height : 200px;
    width : 200px;
    background: blue;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what I think you want:

### http://jsfiddle.net/8heq7w0b/

Better: http://jsfiddle.net/sdL1vead/

```
<div class="box">
<div id="stay-in-place">
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <p>ipsum dolorum caveat emptor veni vidi vici</p>
</div>

<div id="move-in-to-place">
    <h2>I'm on top</h2>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#stay-in-place {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
}
#move-in-to-place {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100%;
    height : 100%;
    width : 100%;
    background: blue;
    opacity:0;
}
.box {
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.box:hover #move-in-to-place {
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s, -webkit-transform 1s;
    transition: all 1s, transform 1s;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    opacity:1;
}
```

Comment: is it possible to achieve the same behavior without absolute positioning?

Comment: No, the absolute positioning makes it relative to the parent.

Answer (score 1):

I made a improved version of http://jsfiddle.net/sdL1vead/ here http://jsfiddle.net/tongadall/trqj1qgo

html

```
<div class="box">
<div class="stay-in-place">
    <h1>hello world</h1>
    <p>ipsum dolorum caveat emptor veni vidi vici</p>
</div>
<div class="move-in-to-place">
    <span>I'm on top</span>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.stay-in-place {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: red;
    position: absolute;
}
.move-in-to-place {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -100%;
    height : 100%;
    width : 100%;
    padding: 8px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    opacity: 0;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
.box {
    margin: 2px;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.box:hover .move-in-to-place {
    bottom: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s, -webkit-transform 0.4s;
    transition: all 0.4s, transform 0.4s;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    opacity: 1;
}
.box:not(hover) .move-in-to-place {
    bottom: -100%;
    -webkit-transition: all 2s, -webkit-transform 2s;
    transition: all 2s, transform 2s;
    width: 100%;
    height: 0;
    opacity: 0;
}
```